# How to draw a multiline chart using fusion charts?

Tags: c#, fusioncharts

I'm trying to draw a multiline chart using fusion charts in a method like below:

```
private void GerarGraficoVarejo(string device)
        {
            DataTable ChartData2 = new DataTable();
            DataTable ChartData3 = new DataTable();
            DataTable ChartData4 = new DataTable();
            // Add columns to data table
            ChartData2.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(System.String));
            ChartData2.Columns.Add("Preço", typeof(System.Double));
            ChartData3.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(System.String));
            ChartData3.Columns.Add("Preço", typeof(System.Double));
            ChartData4.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(System.String));
            ChartData4.Columns.Add("Preço", typeof(System.Double));
            List<Data> datas = _repositorioVivoPreco.recuperarDatasVarejo();
            List<VivoPreco> v = _repositorioVivoPreco.ObterValoresMagalu(device, datas);
            List<VivoPreco> v2 = _repositorioVivoPreco.ObterValoresIplace(device, datas);
            List<VivoPreco> v3 = _repositorioVivoPreco.ObterValoresFastshop(device, datas);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < v.Count; i++)
            {
                ChartData2.Rows.Add(v[i].DataStrVarejo, v[i].ValorAparelhoVarejo);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < v2.Count; i++)
            {
                ChartData3.Rows.Add(v2[i].DataStrVarejo, v2[i].ValorAparelhoVarejo);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < v3.Count; i++)
            {
                ChartData4.Rows.Add(v3[i].DataStrVarejo, v3[i].ValorAparelhoVarejo);
            }
            
            StaticSource source2 = new StaticSource(ChartData2);
            StaticSource source3 = new StaticSource(ChartData3);
            StaticSource source4 = new StaticSource(ChartData4);
                
            DataModel model2 = new DataModel();
                
            model2.DataSources.Add(source2);
            model2.DataSources.Add(source3);
            model2.DataSources.Add(source4);
            Charts.LineChart column2 = new Charts.LineChart("fourthChart");

            // Set the width and the height of the chart
            column2.Width.Pixel(400);
            column2.Height.Pixel(400);
            column2.Data.Source = model2;

            // Set Chart Caption
            column2.Caption.Text = "Comparativo de Preços";                                   
            column2.Legend.Show = false;                   
            column2.XAxis.Text = "Comparativo Magalu";
            column2.YAxis.Text = "Vivo";
            column2.Scrollable = true;
            column2.ThemeName = FusionChartsTheme.ThemeName.FUSION;
            ViewData["GraficoVarejo"] = column2.Render();
        }
```

From what i understood, each line would be a different data source, or am i wrong? Because only one line is being drawn. How can i add more multiple lines to my chart?

Answer (score 1):

FusionCharts.NET is not in active development currently you could use the FusionCharts  ASP.NET wrapper and check.

It would give you the provision to create the Chart object and there you can directly pass the chart type JavaScript alias and the data source in the prescribed format for that chart type and check.

```
Chart newChart = new Chart("msline", "simplechart", "600", "400", "jsonurl", "data.json");
    chart.Text = newChart.Render();
```

The data.json would contain the datasource prescribed for Multiseries Line chart type.

as mentioned below.

```
{
"chart": {
    "caption": "Number of visitors last week",
    "subCaption": "Bakersfield Central vs Los Angeles Topanga",
    "xAxisName": "Day",
    "theme": "fusion"
},
"categories": [
    {
        "category": [
            {
                "label": "Mon"
            },
            {
                "label": "Tue"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wed"
            },
            {
                "vline": "true",
                "lineposition": "0",
                "color": "#6baa01",
                "labelHAlign": "center",
                "labelPosition": "0",
                "label": "National holiday",
                "dashed": "1"
            },
            {
                "label": "Thu"
            },
            {
                "label": "Fri"
            },
            {
                "label": "Sat"
            },
            {
                "label": "Sun"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"dataset": [
    {
        "seriesname": "Bakersfield Central",
        "data": [
            {
                "value": "15123"
            },
            {
                "value": "14233"
            },
            {
                "value": "25507"
            },
            {
                "value": "9110"
            },
            {
                "value": "15529"
            },
            {
                "value": "20803"
            },
            {
                "value": "19202"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "seriesname": "Los Angeles Topanga",
        "data": [
            {
                "value": "13400"
            },
            {
                "value": "12800"
            },
            {
                "value": "22800"
            },
            {
                "value": "12400"
            },
            {
                "value": "15800"
            },
            {
                "value": "19800"
            },
            {
                "value": "21800"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"trendlines": [
    {
        "line": [
            {
                "startvalue": "17022",
                "color": "#6baa01",
                "valueOnRight": "1",
                "displayvalue": "Average"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}